# Stacking font symbols and aligning the spaces around a font using html5/css

Tags: css, html, unicode, fonts, text-alignment

I am trying to insert a symbol at a fixed position and stack another symbol over it using font-symbols. But the spacing around the font is preventing me to do so. (note the symbol is from unicode-font)

So far I have tried adjusting z-index and line-height, which enable me to adjust the height of the total space taken by the element and the font but they are still misaligned. I have tried adjusting the positioning or vertical alignment. What other alignment modification can be done with the font itself?

Here is the code:

```
#back
{
font-size: 15em;
font-weight:100;
line-height:1.15em;
height:0.9em;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
vertical-align: bottom;  
 z-index:300; 
 position:fixed; 
 top:155px; 
 background-color:white;
 }

#front {
font-size: 15em;
font-weight:100;
line-height:1.15em;
height:0.9em;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid black;
vertical-align: bottom;
 z-index:1000; 
 position:fixed; 
 top:165px;
 left:30px; 
 background-color:white;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gns07zax/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but there are plenty of ways to position content in CSS. There's `position: relative` which seems like it might be better for your application than `position: fixed`. Also `transform: translate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are offset in the actual font itself . Considering they're essentially 'text' in this regard, you can offset them by making use of the [**line-height**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) property.

Note that your snippet has a number of incorrect selectors, such as the omission of the hastag in the ID selectors. However, I assume you're trying to align the cards to their boxes, and you're looking for a value of about `186px`.

Here's a minimal example showcasing this:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15em;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  height: 0.9em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#back {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
}

#front {
  position: fixed;
  left: 180px;
  background-color: white;
}

#back, #front {
  line-height: 186px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='back'>&#127137</h1>
<h1 id='front'>&#x1F0A1</h1>
```

You may need to change positioning to suit.

However, you may find it more beneficial to change the `height` to `1em`, which will allow the cards to be fully contained by their borders. In this case, you're looking for `0.875em` for the `line-height`.

Here's a minimal example showcasing this:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15em;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.15em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#back {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

#front {
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  background-color: white;
}

#back, #front {
  line-height: 0.875em;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='back'>&#127137</h1>
<h1 id='front'>&#x1F0A1</h1>
```

Hope this helps! :)